# How to visualize Caffe parameters?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, deep-learning, caffe

I've been searching for a way to visualize parameters in Caffe after traning the network, I found [this link](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb#2.-Load-net-and-set-up-input-preprocessing). it send a transpose of parameter with

```
filters = net.params['conv1'][0].data
vis_square(filters.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1))
```

Which i don't understand why it transpose the data? and in the **vis_square** it use this code:

```
data = data.reshape((n, n) + data.shape[1:]).transpose((0, 2, 1, 3) + tuple(range(4, data.ndim + 1)))
data = data.reshape((n * data.shape[1], n * data.shape[3]) + data.shape[4:])
```

Which is too compressed to understand, any explanation would be appreciated. and then when i changed the code to get conv2 instead of conv1:

```
filters = net.params['conv2'][0].data
vis_square(filters.transpose(0, 2, 3, 1))
```

I get

> **TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data**

, Is there any different between conv1 and conv2 which cause this error ? How can we change the code to fix it and it work for all layer ?

Some debugging data :

```
net.params['conv1'][0].data.shape : (96, 3, 11, 11)
net.params['conv1'][1].data.shape : (96,)
net.params['conv2'][0].data.shape : (256, 48, 5, 5)
net.params['conv2'][1].data.shape : (256,)
net.params['conv3'][0].data.shape : (384, 256, 3, 3)
net.params['conv3'][1].data.shape : (384,)

for conv2:
data.shape[0] :  256
np.sqrt(data.shape[0]) :  16.0
np.ceil(np.sqrt(data.shape[0])) :  16.0

data.shape[0] :  256
data.shape[0:] :  (256, 6, 6, 48)
data.shape[1] :  6
data.shape[1:] :  (6, 6, 48)
data.ndim :  4
range(4, data.ndim + 1)) :  [4]
tuple(range(4, data.ndim + 1)) :  (4,)
```

AND after :

```
data = np.pad(data, padding, mode='constant', constant_values=1)
```

for conv2:

```
data.shape :  (10, 12, 10, 12, 3)
```

and after

```
data = data.reshape((n, n) + data.shape[1:]).transpose((0, 2, 1, 3) + tuple(range(4, data.ndim + 1)))
```

data became :

```
data.shape :  (120, 120, 3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you inspected is written to visualize (i.e., convert to RGB image) convolutional filters.
The shape of `conv1` filters (in your example) is `(96, 3, 11, 11)` which means
-  `96` : you have 96 filters in `conv1` of your net (i.e., `num_output: 96`), therefore you would wish to view 96 different filters.
- `3` : the input dimension of each filter is 3, because the input to `conv1` in your net is an RGB image with three channels.
- `11, 11`: the spatial size of each kernel/filter in your case is 11x11 (i.e., `kernel_size: 11`).
Therefore, to visualize 96 filters as 11x11x3 thumbnails.

However, when trying to visualize `conv2` (or any other deeper layer) you have a problem. There is no longer RGB meaning to filter dimensions. The filters of `conv2` work on the output feature of `conv1` (which in your case is a 96-dim space). To date, AFAIK, there is no straight-forward way to convert a 96-dim data to a simple 3D RGB representation.
So, you cannot use the same code to visualize `conv2` filters. You must use some other method for visualization.